# Revit Python Shell without a project open

Tags: python, revit-api, revitpythonshell

Trying to run the NewProjectDocument command from Revit API when no project is open but I am getting this error. It seems to work fine when a project is open.
Any suggestions?

[RPS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op0Ps.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please update your question with you code (rather than a link)? You can copy and paste straight from the console.

In regards to you error, its line after `# Define Revit Document`

Youre trying to tell RPS that `doc` is the currenly open Document, but not having a document open throws the error.